# Invalid URI Error using SyndicationFeed

Tags: c#, syndication-feed

I run this;

```
var r = XmlReader.Create("http://www.pwop.com/feed.aspx?show=dotnetrocks&filetype=master");
var rssData = SyndicationFeed.Load(r);
```

And this exception gets thrown:

*Error in line 17 position 134. An error was encountered when parsing the feed's XML. Refer to the inner exception for more details.*

With this inner exception:

*"Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."*

Suggestions to make this parse?

Comment: That code works just fine for me (I iterate `r` rather than calling your `SyndicationFeed.Load()` method).  Did you perhaps over-simplify the code when posting it?

Comment: Yeppers its the SyndicationFeed that is throwing the error, not the XmlReader

Comment: Not sure what SyndicationFeed is doing then.  `r` reads the feed without problems.  You will have to show what SyndicationFeed.Load() is doing.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515814(v=vs.110).aspx I am not sure best way to show this use Reflector I guess?

Comment: Ah did not realize that is a library function.  Perhaps to try and narrow it down, place the RSS feed in a text file and create the XmlReader from that text file.  Perhaps also try a different RSS feed (perhaps there is something malformed in your current one).